# java for freebsd

Tags: unix, installation, java, freebsd

I am trying to install java on freebsd 7.X and i have done following thing so far

[download the tar file from this link](http://www.freebsdfoundation.org/cgi-bin/download?download=diablo-caffe-freebsd7-i386-1.6.0_07-b02.tar.bz2)
and store the file in

```
cd /usr/ports/distfiles/
```

after that i run

```
cd /usr/ports/java/diablo-jre16 **or** 
cd /usr/ports/java/diablo-jdk16
make config install clean
```

and uncheck all the options in config screen

now after doing all this now i am getting following message to indicate for amd version even if my server is using **intel Core2Quad Q9550 2.83 GHz**

```
mail# make install
===>  Vulnerability check disabled, database not found
===>  License check disabled, port has not defined LICENSE
===>  Found saved configuration for diablo-jdk-1.6.0.07.02_12

Because of licensing restrictions,
you must fetch the distribution 
manually.

Please access

     http://www.FreeBSDFoundation.org/cgi-bin/download?download=diablo-caffe-freebsd7-amd64-1.6.0_07-b02.tar.bz2

with a web browser and "Accept" the
End User License Agreement for  "Caffe
Diablo 1.6.0".

Please place the downloaded file(s)
in /usr/ports/distfiles.

*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/java/diablo-jdk16.
mail#
```

(as before i was getting error for tzupdater so i downloaded tzupdater-1_3_29-2010f.zip and put it in a cd /usr/ports/distfiles/ folder)

***status updated***

i have installed it successfully ( i guess) after downloading the amd package but now when i entered command

```
cd /usr/local/diablo-jdk1.6.0/bin/
```

and then

```
java command
```

to check whether its being installed or not then it is showing me

```
java: Command not found.
```

Though java is listed in that dir

Comment: AMD invented the 64-bit extensions to the instruction set used by your Intel processor, so they got named after AMD. It has nothing to do with the actual brand of your processor.

Answer (score 2):

It's ok, if you installed 64-bit version. Intel uses same instruction set (exception is Itanium), so just download file mentioned in error message.

Comment: i have installed it successfully after downloading the amd package but now when i entered int  cd /usr/local/diablo-jdk1.6.0/bin/
and type java command to check whether its being installed or not then it is showing me java: Command not found. 


Though java is listed in that dir

Comment: try reading FreeBSD handbook: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/basics.html
In *nix commands searched only in $PATH, unlike DOS, where commands first searched in current directory and then in %PATH%. So if you want to run `java` type `/usr/local/diablo-jdk1.6.0/bin/java` or `./java` after `cd /usr/local/diablo-jdk1.6.0/bin/`

Comment: You sometimes have to logout/login to get your system to recognize that there are new binaries installed..

Answer (score 1):

The port should install the javavm wrapper, which installs links in /usr/local/bin.
Thus, you should be able to type java -version anywhere.